# align objects to an axis or to each other

Tags: mesh, objects, axis

is there a way to align objects up with each other along an axis?  I know how to align using scale and vertices, but I need to do this with complete objects.  Basically I'm looking for the standard align tools I see in other software.  [image]

[Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/tools.html) indicates there should be a tool available for this, but it is not in my Objects menu.  Is it something I need to add on?  I tried Align to active, that was a mistake as I was not able to choose to do it only on one axis.

I am using version 2.82.

[image]